# Inheritance in Node.Js + Expressjs

Tags: node.js, inheritance, express

I am trying to achieve something like following in Node.js and Express.js, not able to find good examples of active this. Help appreciated.

```
base.js
--------
module.exports = {
  baseFunction: function(){
    .....
  }
}

child.js
--------
module.exports = {
  require('base'),

  ***** Some Magical Code ****** 

  childFunction: function(){
    ..... 
  }
}



CallProgram.js
--------------
var child = require('child');
child.baseFunction();
```

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? Incase you are not aware of module system of node refer http://itsallabtamil.blogspot.in/2012/01/nodejs-modules-and-export-explained.html

Comment: I have few generic methods which i do not wish to repeat in 25 child modules. I was looking for something like `require('base');` in child programs which will enable access to base methods without having to duplicating the code. I might override the code some child classes if required. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do is correct but the way you are doing is wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
function extend(a, b) {
  var result = Object.create(a);
  for (var prop in b) {
    if (b.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      result[prop] = b[prop];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

module.exports = extend(require('base'), {
  ***** Some Magical Code ****** 

  childFunction: function(){
    ..... 
  }
});
```

The extend function will create a new object with `a` as its prototype and will copy all properties of `b` onto it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [ZinkyJS](https://zinkyjs.github.io/), It offers a very clean way to make routing inheritance